# Can I add a image to the graph to clearly mark a time break

Tags: highcharts

I have a time series graph with live data streaming in and I'm adding an axis break any time I have more than 30 seconds of missing data.

I would like to add an image/icon to clearly indicate this has happened as shown in the attached picture.

Can someone help me with how to add the icon to a time series graph?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using a plotband to illustrate this? It would simplyfy the js code. Example of a plotband: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-zindex/. If this is not an option, you can have a look at this example where there is added icons to a graph: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Thanks ewolden, plotbands will do the trick!